# Detect first non-empty element

Tags: xpath

After reading the most relevant Xpath questions about detecting empty nodes, I still can not find the first non-empty element. The dataset looks like:

```
<div> 
  <p>
    <elem>&#xa0;</elem>
  </p>
  <p>
    <elem>&nbsp;</elem>
  </p>
  <p>
    <elem>&#xa0;</elem>
  </p>
  <p>
    <elem>&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;</elem>
  </p>
  <p>
    <elem>Application</elem>
  </p>
  <p>
    <elem>Other text that should not be detected.</elem>
  </p>
  <p>
    <elem>&#xa0;</elem>
  </p>
  <p>
    <elem>Second application</elem>
  </p>
</div>
```

Basically the empty elements should not be taken into account, and we only want to detect the first `Application` element. We've been testing a lot with `normalize-space`, and related functions but can not get this working.

The main problem are the empty elements. The check we have right now solves the positioning flawlessly, but fails once the html contains `&nbsp;` elements:

```
/div/p[position() < 3]//*[normalize-space()='Application']
```

So, how can we ignore empty elements? This only is possible via an additional step in between?

Comment: The problem is that you don't *have* empty elements in the first place. `normalize-space()` only normalizes whitespace characters - I am not sure if it normalizes `&#xa0;` elements (I would assume so since they are basically linefeeds), but it certainly doesn't touch `&nbsp;` since no-break spaces are special characters and not regular whitespace for the purposes of that function.

Answer (score 0):

In my definition an empty element does not have any child nodes so `//*[not(node()]` would select all empty elements by that definition. If you want to allow certain text content then you could check `normalize-space` after removing them e.g. `//*[not(*) and not(normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', '')))]`. Basically you need to list all characters as the second argument of the `translate` call that you want to remove before checking with normalize-space. And the XPath expression I have written would work inside XSLT where the numeric character reference is parsed by an XML parser, in general it depends on the host language you use XPath with how to escape characters.